# $I$ is an *initial segment* of $\mathbb{N} \implies I=\mathbb{N}$ or $I=I_n$ [Proof Verification]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Please check if my proof has any error. Thank you for your help!

Definition:

> $A$ is an *initial segment* of $B \iff A \neq \varnothing$ and $\forall b \in B(a \in A \wedge b \leq a \implies b \in A)$.
>
> $I_n=\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \leq n\}$

Theorem:

> $I$ is an *initial segment* of $\mathbb{N} \implies I=\mathbb{N}$ or $I=I_n$

Proof:

> It is clear that $(m \not \in I \wedge m \leq n \implies n \not \in I)$.
>
> Let $C = \mathbb{N} \setminus I$. There are two possible cases.
>
> 1. $I=N$
>
> The theorem is trivially true.
>
> 2. $I \neq N$
>
> $\implies C \neq \varnothing$. By well-ordering principle, $C$ has the least element $c_0 \implies c_0 > 0$ (If $c_0=0$, then $I=\varnothing$).
>
> $c_0 > 0 \implies c_0=n+1$.
>
> $p \in I \implies p < c_0 \implies p<n+1 \implies p \leq n \implies p \in I_n$. Thus $I \subseteq I_n$.
>
> $p \in I_n \implies p \leq n \implies p < n+1 \implies p<c_0 \implies p \not \in C \implies p  \not \in \mathbb{N} \setminus I \implies p \in I$. Thus $I_n \subseteq I$.
>
> $I \subseteq I_n \wedge I_n \subseteq I \implies I=I_n$.

Comment: Your proof seems correct, however, it would be better if you elaborate your writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are two cases.
If I has an upper bound, then I has a maximum m.
Thus I = $I_m$.
If I does not have an upper bound, then show I = N.